# Xtext: Customize how Generator is called

Tags: xtext

I would like to change the way the Generator is called in my project. As default it is called when the model is safed, but I would need it to be called when enter is hit for example. Can anyone explane where and how to do this?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the generator is called by the build. If you want to call it manually, you need to do that yourself. You may use [an article I wrote about this](https://dietrich-it.de/xtext/2011/10/15/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu/) as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you, calling the generator from the context menu is exactly what I want! I simply step by step changed that for my own project but when clicking on "Generate Code" at the editor , not even the execute method in the GenerationHandler class which I created in the .ui project in a new ui.handler package is reached. Any Idea respectively how can I debug that?

Comment: please check the error log for messages. likely you have an error in plugin.xml

Comment: Thanks, I checked them - When launching eclipse I dont get different messages when using IBuilderParticipant compared to the customized version. Other than when starting Eclipse I dont get any error logs at all. When clicking generate code in the context menu simply nothing happens. Dont really know how to go on here, but starting the code generation from saving editor  really is no option for my project. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: When using the extension for the packageexplorer too i get the message "Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources". and "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.epsilon.emf.dt.EmfUtilPlugin.getPreferenceStore()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.epsilon.emf.dt.EmfUtilPlugin.getDefault()" is null at..." but that cant be the reason why nothing happens when using the open editor right?

Comment: this is unrealted. i dont get it. is there a context menu entry or not. can you klick it or not. did you triple check plugin.xml (file extension and executableextensionfactory?

Comment: Sorry, yes there is a context menu entry but when clicking nothing happens, so the handlerclass is never reached. Do I maybe have to add it to the runtime?

Comment: i cannot follow you. you add it to plugin.xml and configure the fileextension/dsl it is used for there

Comment: can you share a complete hello world reproducer via github/etc

Comment: https://github.com/christophbinder/repo.git  Simply nothing is reached when clicking on "Generate Code" in the context menu in the editor. Thank you!

Comment: there is an error log entry related to your code.

Comment: injecting `IGenerator2`, `Provider<EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess2>` and call doGenerate with (resource, fsa, new GeneratorContext()) and using core.commands instead of ui.commands for imports
should do the trick.

Comment: perfekt thank you!! had breakpoints at the extensionfactory and since they werent reached I thought the mistake cant be in the Handler class.